# Where to find the UK's regions map on GeoJSON format

Tags: svg, geojson

I am trying to get the uk's regions map, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regions_of_England, on GeoJSON format to use it on a web visits map on a website. Is there any place where you can get the data for different countries on GeoJSON  format?

Comment: They're available here: http://geoportal.statistics.gov.uk/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can download the UK administrative boundaries from: https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/opendatadownload/products.html

Scroll down the page until you see Boundary-Line.

You'll need to convert the shape files to geojson with a GIS tool. Here's a step-by-step tutorial:

http://blog-en.openalfa.com/how-to-add-interactive-maps-to-a-web-site/

The shape files supplied by the Ordinance Survey have different levels of detail. It sounds like you'd just need to convert the `european_region_region.shp` shape file.

```
ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON european_region_region.json european_region_region.shp
```

EDIT: don't forget to [convert from Northing/Easting to Lat/Long](http://www.flyingtophat.co.uk/blog/10/converting-a-shapefile-s-projection) if you want to work with Leaflet, Google Maps, etc

```
ogr2ogr -t_srs WGS84 -f GeoJSON european_region_region.json european_region_region.shp
```

The Ordinance Survey have a licensing policy that you'll need to comply with:

https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/oswebsite/docs/licences/os-opendata-licence.pdf

Comment: Thanks yaygooby. That was definitely the map I needed!

Comment: Actually, this is the map of Great Britain, which is not UK, is it? It is missing the Northern Ireland part.

Comment: Unfortunately the links you point to now seem to offer downloads for the "*.sld" files instead of "*.shp". I've not been able to find the shp files as described in your answer.

Comment: Did you follow the 'Free Download' link that's listed under the Boundary Line product? That's new; is that where you got you .sld files from? To get the shape files, click the [download link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3387880/OS%20download%20link.png) and then scroll to the bottom of the page, click Next and fill out the form. You'll get a link to the files by email.

Comment: I just wanted to add some clarity to this is... The reason that Northern Ireland is not featured in administrative maps of Great Britain is that the UK is actually the United Kingdom of Great Britain _and_ Northern Ireland. Great Britain is a separate entity from Northern Ireland. Great Britain is made up England, Scotland and Wales. There are no UK level administrative boundaries. Boundaries for Great Britain come from the OSGB projected in EPSG:27700 and for Northern Ireland from OSNI projected onto the Irish EPSG:29900.

Comment: If you need to visually check or edit geojson then you can use something like http://rob-murray.github.io/gb-geojson/ which supports WGS84 and BNG

Comment: Worth noting here is that Scotland, Wales and NI do not have Regions - for the purpose of UK- and GB-wide statistics, it is common to treat, Wales, Scotland and NI as three extra Regions to add to the English ones. The OS definitions include Scotland and Wales boundaries, not NI. Also note that the Scottish boundary in particular is very large, due to the amount of coastline and islands.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BT_postcode_area   you can use a webservice to get boundaries for any district(including northern Ireland,etc.)    https://www.mashape.com/vanitysoft/uk-boundaries-io

Answer (score 3):

There's a useful github repository containing GeoJSON boundary data for UK, converted from ONS shapefiles https://github.com/martinjc/UK-GeoJSON

- Local Authority Districts (LAD)
- European Electoral Regions (EER)
- Westminster Parliamentary Constituencies (WPC)
- Electoral Wards
- Eurostat boundaries (NUTS level 1 & 2) for England, Scotland and Wales
- Statistical areas (super output etc.) used by ONS

Northern Ireland is the exception to these due to the strict licensing of the government agency "public" information.

Comment: As an update to this, Northern Ireland boundary sets are now openly licensed and available from https://www.opendatani.gov.uk/

Answer (score 1):

If you just want GeoJson files of UK boundaries (includes NI) you should just use - http://mapit.mysociety.org

Northern Ireland LGD (Council) boundaries - http://mapit.mysociety.org/areas/LGD.html

Comment: I've tried using these but 2 common problems: 1 - The region GeoJSON files are huge (Mbs). 2 - they return an errror when being used in Google Maps "UncaughtInvalidValueError: Not a Feature or FeatureCollection"

Comment: There's an additional condition that I'm guessing people miss with MySociety is that unlike the OS, the data is not free for commercial use, or even for download to use in what ends up as a commercial project. So be careful with copyright!

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell whether you're looking for country-level or subcountry-level boundaries. If it's the former, then:

Some of the examples for d3.js use a GeoJSON file that contains all the countries in the world. You can find it here: https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/master/examples/data/world-countries.json.

D3.js is also an excellent framework for actually rendering this data in svg, so if you haven't already, you might wanna look into it. For example: http://bl.ocks.org/2206590.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am using D3.js already. I have found UK's map and UK's map based in counties and different examples. But what I really want is a map of the 9 regions of England, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regions_of_England, plus Scotland, Wales and Northern Ireland.

Comment: Ok, yeah, then that wasn't helpful. There should be a way to export this data out of an open source tool. I've never done that, but this tutorial will probably help you: http://oscarvillarreal.com/2012/07/12/create-any-map-of-the-world-in-svg/.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the ONS Website Data, which you can downlaod in different formats

https://data.gov.uk/data/search?theme-primary=Mapping&res_format=GeoJSON