# Uncaught InvalidValueError: not a Feature or FeatureCollection

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps, geojson

After seeing a recent [video](http://youtu.be/cwpmvI4vxNQ) by the Google Devs I decided to do a regional map of the UK. There were a couple of possibilities mentioned on this site that I've since had to dismiss*

So I ended up using this site (example page of data downloads): http://mapit.mysociety.org/area/11804.html

Notice the **GeoJSON download** as the third link down? Its about a 1Mb file size. When I first tried using it with my map:

```js
function initMap(){
    var ukc = new google.maps.LatLng(54.8, -4.6);
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 5,
        center: ukc
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
    map.data.loadGeoJson('http://local.mapsite.com:8080/app/jsondata/eastern.json');
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    initMap();
});
```

I got the above error: **Uncaught InvalidValueError: not a Feature or FeatureCollection**

### Fix Attempt 1 - Google it

Googling the error came back with nothing useful.

### Fix Attempt 2 - Shrink it

I thought maybe it was the sheer size of the beast so I shrank it using mapshaper.org to a more manageable 10K. **Still no luck!**

### Fix Attempt 3 - Lint it

Maybe my GeoJSON was badly formatted? But how could it be considering it was right there working on mapit.org but I found this wonderful site for linting GeoJSON data: http://geojsonlint.com/ - The linting worked! Apparently the GeoJSON worked so well that it drew my polygon of East Anglia on the UK in all its glory (note geojsonlint uses OpenStreetMap). But still **No Luck**

### Fix Attempt 4 - TopoJson

Hoping I could combine the regions and compress at the same time I thought desperately that topojson would work. I tried - I still got that same error. Here's a link to my topojson file shared on Google Drive: [someregions.json](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B42Aec8RKcHtTFpmem9OdlNHSkE/edit?usp=sharing) **No luck**.

### Fix Attempt 5 - Add Feature code to start of JSON

The current GeoJSON file starts
    {"bbox":[-0.745702,51.448473,1.767999,52.98991],"type":"GeometryCollection","geometries":...

I added:

```
{"type": "Feature", "bbox":[-0.745702,51.448473,1.767999,52.98991],"type":"GeometryCollection","geometries":
```

### Fix Attempt 6

Retry different regions as they donm't contain the bbox parameter near the start but simply start 
    { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -3.155785, 53.427385 ], [ -3.151533, 53.427328 ], [...

Still **no luck**.

### In (Failed) Conclusion

Even though I proved my file was *small enough*, *linted* and *worked elsewhere* I still got those infuriating error messages from the console when attempting to put them on my map.

```
Uncaught InvalidValueError: not a Feature or FeatureCollection
```

Here is my shrunk GeoJSON file publically shared via GDrive: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B42Aec8RKcHtNVNZZUxqV0Y5Rkk/edit?usp=sharing

My next attempts will involve topojson to compress all regions into one with internal borders but I wanted to check here first to see if anyone knows what my problem could be? Because that may be another few hours of futile energy wasted.

* Attempting to use Ordanance Survey data failed as they provided SHD data and not SHP as stated in a previous question on the subject. So I couldn't convert it into GeoJSON using ogr2ogr.

Comment: Just to note that Ordnance Survey definitely do provide SHP data, as that's what we use to import into MapIt :) MapIt also has a simplify_tolerance parameter to reduce the complexity of the returned shape.

Comment: Hi @MatthewSomerville. I followed the instructions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13515173/288001) which recommends finding the Ordinance Survey's SHP data [here](http://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/business-and-government/help-and-support/products/styled-layer-descriptors.html) but found only the SHD data files. Any chance you could point me in the right direction?

Comment: I see the comment you left on that answer received a response which answers your question here - you need to tick the box on the page linked to, and submit the form to be sent an email to download the Boundary-Line data. Alternatively you can get it from the cache of that data we maintain at http://parlvid.mysociety.org/os/

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The specification for GeoJSON can be found at http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html
Relevant (though experimental) Google Maps API documentation can be found at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#Data

So it looks like for GeoJSON to be acceptable by Google Maps, you need to wrap a Polygon (or similar) returned by MapIt in a Feature or FeatureCollection, here's an example for bermuda-triangle:

```js
  { "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
      { "type": "Feature",
         "geometry": {
           "type": "Polygon",
           "coordinates": 
              [
                [
                  [-80.190262,25.774252],
                  [-66.118292,18.466465],
                  [-64.75737,32.321384],
                  [-80.190262,25.774252]
                ]
              ]
         }
      }
    ]
  }
```

for the data provided by http://mapit.mysociety.org/area/11804.html it has to be:

```js
  { "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
      { "type": "Feature",
         "geometry": /** paste here the complete output of 
                         http://mapit.mysociety.org/area/11804.geojson **/
      }
    ]
  }
```

Comment: MapIt returns valid GeoJSON, as far as I can see. As the spec you link to states, "A GeoJSON object may represent a geometry, a feature, or a collection of features." and "Each of the examples below represents a complete GeoJSON object." Could you point out where a Polygon must be wrapped in a Feature and a FeatureCollection to be valid? It sounds like Google Maps mandates Feature or FeatureCollection, though I can't find any API docs on that.

Comment: The reference may be found at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#Data (note that Data belongs to the experimental API-version, maybe the documentation will be more detailed in the future). Most of the  methods there require a feature(of course you need a FeatureCollection when you have multiple features)

Comment: So the Google Maps API mandates Feature or FeatureCollection, as I suggested, but that is not the same thing as saying the GeoJSON returned by MapIt is "wrong", nor that according to the GeoJSON specification that a Polygon must be wrapped in a Feature and FeatureCollection.

Answer (score 17):

I had the same problem (or at least similar) and solved it by introducing one extra step.

Origin of the data:
My semantic Network delivers on a first round request the data about the caves in Southern France in GeoJSON format. This is directly imported via:

> map.data.loadGeoJson(theUrl);

As we might want to work independent of the semantic network with these data (the app is a thick client) the caves are locally stored via `jStorage`.
Iterating of the features of the map and storing these objects directly in `jStorage` failed because of circular references.
I made a handcrafted routine (not generic enough but suiting the purpose) to transform the `map.data.Feature` into a javascript object that could be stored.

When getting the data from the store:

```
var cave =  $.jStorage.get(key);
map.data.addGeoJson(cave);
```

throws the `Uncaught InvalidValueError: not a Feature or FeatureCollection` error.

But:

```
var geojson = JSON.parse(cave);
map.data.addGeoJson(geojson);
```

Works fine.

My interpretation is that the function `addGeoJson` needs a javascript object and not a string.

Sample geoJson (the orignal "cave") value:

```
{ "type": "Feature", "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [5.368743302306143, 44.0421921072459]},"id": "84.MON.014", "properties": {"nom": "Aven du Grand Guérin", "nid": "7b4703-f387f6f544-0750e59f441be7bb30a7e097c5d725f7", "nature": "Aven", "nodeTime": 1400743203325, "dataId": "5b66137c-1461fdfe5ca-f528764d624db129b32c21fbca0cb8d6", "status": 1}}
```

Comment: This answer fixed what was driving me crazy tonight. In reading the Google Maps API it says that the addGeoJson function requires a PARSED object https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Data

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to load the data to a JavaScript variable then use this

`var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);
 var data = map.data.loadGeoJson("GeoJSONfilename.geojson");`

googleMap is the div id where you want your map to be presented, and GeoJSONfilename.geojson where you saved your GeoJSON data.

Comment: var mapProp = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(41.152036, -81.336186),
    zoom: 12,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, but the problem was something very simple. On my GeoJSON, instead of

```
"type": "Feature"
```

I had

```
"type": "feature"
```

(note the lowercase 'f')

Once I fixed this, the error was gone.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error message. My `.json` file missed one line of code on line 2:
`"type": "FeatureCollection",`

Before I had in my `.json`-file:

```
{
  "features": []
...
}
```

It fixed it for me with:

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": []
...
}
```