# Using the response from an asynchronous call with the Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, google-maps-api-3

I have a .json file that I'm trying to import as a text string.

This is the exact file contents:

```
{ "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ 1.5887868, 50.8315241 ], [ 1.5830702, 50.8466931 ].......  ] ] ] }
```

I'm trying to import it using this:

```
jsonString = jQuery.get('./polygons/1.json', function(data) {    
  console.log(data);            
});
```

However, `console.log(data)` is coming across as an array, and I don't want it to - I just want the literal text string, just as it is in the file.

[image]

How do I accomplish this?

## Update

So my entire code is:

```
jsonString = jQuery.get('./polygons/1.json', function(data) {    

  return JSON.stringify(data);

});
```

[image]

But now I get this screenshot below:

I guess it's the `responseText` that I'm trying to get out.  Why is `jQuery.get` adding all this additional info into my file?  What am I doing wrong?

## Second Update

I always feel bad when someone takes *their* time to explain something to me, and I don't understand it.  **So,** this whole thing exists so that I can pull **dynamic** data into `jsonString`, depending on what the user wants.

Right now though, I'm having to accomplish this feat by making individual files with the geodata coordinates, then utilizing it using `map.data.loadGeoJson('./maps_polygons/' + territory + '.json');`

```
function mapClick(data) {

territory = data; //the section of the map that the user clicks on, e.g. `california` or `texas`

var mapOpt = {
  center:new google.maps.LatLng(50.477971, 0.482999),  
  zoom:8,  
  };

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapOpt);

map.data.loadGeoJson('./maps_polygons/' + territory + '.json');


google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

}
```

Now, this WORKS, but I felt that it **must** be incredibly inefficient, so I wanted to hold all of the coordinates in a single file, and bring them in dynamically as the main input from `function mapClick(data)` changed.  This has GOT to be possible, and from what you've all shown me, I can write an `ajax` query, or use `jQuery.get` from **within a function**, and that will bring the json string in, but that does me no good, because it's stuck inside of that function and I can't get to it.

This is my frustration...

## Final Update

Okay - shout-out to [this page](http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascript-callback-functions-and-use-them/) and [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22603220/uncaught-invalidvalueerror-not-a-feature-or-featurecollection), as well as @Lye-Fish for finally helping me understand how this all works.

In searching SO tonight, I found tons of posts about aspects of this topic, so I wanted to die it all in how I finally got these two things to work:

1. The idea of *getting something out of an ajax call* (the original reason for my post)
2. How to tie that back into the Google Maps API.

**The HTML**

```
<area shape="poly" coords="..." href="#" alt="california" onClick="mapClick(alt)"/>
```

**The Javascript**

```
function mapClick(data) {

territory = data;

function getPolygons(territory, passTodoWork) {
    jQuery.get('./maps_polygons/'+ territory +'.json', function(data, status, jqXHR) {    
        var coordinates = JSON.parse(jqXHR.responseText);
        passTodoWork(territory,coordinates);
    });
}
function drawMap(firstItem, secondItem) {
    var mapOpt = {
    center:new google.maps.LatLng(50.367247, 2.745326),  
    zoom:8,  
    };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapOpt);


  map.data.addGeoJson(secondItem);

  map.data.setStyle({  
    fillColor: '#2b86cc',
    strokeColor: '#1e5c8c'
  });


  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
}

getPolygons(territory, drawMap);

}
```

*note, I don't utilize `territory` in the final `drawMap` function - that's part of another piece of code that made this all too long to prove the point...*

Comment: `console.log(JSON.stringify(data))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, and most importantly, your `jsonString` variable is *not* going to hold the response. It's going to hold the jqXHR object for the request, which will have the response eventually, but you need to access it inside the callback.

Second, using `JSON.stringify` is *not* a proper solution. It doesn't make sense to serialize data that's already available to you in its serialized form.

The `jqXHR` object holds the `.responseText` property that will give you the actual unparsed response body. You don't need to get it from that variable either. You can get it from the 3rd parameter to the callback.

```
jQuery.get('./polygons/1.json', function(data, status, jqXHR) {    
    console.log(jqXHR.responseText);
});
```

The `return` statement you had does nothing at all, so I dropped it. The `jQuery.get` does not block execution, which means you need to pick it up inside the callback.

---

If you truly don't want it parsed, then I'd recommend changing your response headers so that jQuery doesn't realize it's JSON data. I'm pretty sure that's why it's parsing it for you automatically.

If you change your header from this:

```
Content-Type: application/json
```

to this:

```
Content-Type: text/plain
```

It should work.

---

Or you could just make a `jQuery.ajax` request, and specify `"dataType: text"`, and that may work too. The `jQuery.get` does give you another argument you can pass to override the guesswork, but it seems it's limited to `xml`, `json`, `html` or `script`.

---

To deal with the *asynchronous* nature of the code, you need to pick up the execution inside the callback. Since you probably don't want a whole bunch of application code in there, you can put it in a different function and invoke it, passing it the data.

```
jQuery.get('./polygons/1.json', function(data, status, jqXHR) {    
    console.log(jqXHR.responseText);
    // do some other stuff in here

    doWork(jqXHR.responseText);
});

function doWork(data) {
    console.log("Now we have it here: ", data);
}
```

---

If this same type of request will be made for different purposes, you can put it inside another function and pass a callback function to be invoked for the different situations.

```
function getPolygons(callback) {
    jQuery.get('./polygons/1.json', function(data, status, jqXHR) {    
        console.log(jqXHR.responseText);
        // do some other stuff in here

        callback(jqXHR.responseText);
    });
}

function doWork(data) {
    console.log("Now we have it here: ", data);
}

function doOtherWork(data) {
    console.log("And now it's here: ", data);
}

getPolygons(doWork);

// ...some other part of the app...

getPolygons(doOtherWork);
```

---

If you're having trouble still with jQuery doing stuff you don't want, just make the XHR request yourself.

```
function getPolygons(callback) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
    xhr.open("GET", "./polygons/1.json", true);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState === 4) {
            console.log(this.responseText);
        // do some other stuff in here

            callback(this.responseText);
        }
    };
    xhr.send(null);
}
```

You can also check the `this.status` in the callback for HTTP response codes if they're meaningful to you. FYI, `this` is the same object held by the `xhr` variable.

Comment: First off - I really appreciate you taking the time to explain this to me.  My issue here is that I'm trying to get this `.json` file and assign it to the `jsonString` variable, so I have `jsonString = jQuery.get.....`  But it's still returning the entire thing, and not `jqXHR.responseText` because that's happening inside the function.  How do I get `jqXHR.responseText` to be applied to my actual variable that I can then use OUTSIDE of the function?

Comment: That's fine - I can change it to an ajax request, but I still don't get how to access it outside of the ajax success call then...

Comment: @JohnWu: You can't. This is the nature of asynchronous programming. Your flow of execution *continues* inside the callback.

Comment: You could put the rest of the code inside another function and invoke it from inside the callback if you wish. That way you can separate the code logically. I'll update with a couple examples.

Comment: @JohnWu: Frankly, you don't need jQuery to make these requests. It's simple to just do it yourself and you're not stuck with their API trying to do things you don't want. I'll give another update that shows how.

Comment: I feel bad asking for more help when you've already done so much.  The problem for me isn't getting this text anymore - all 4 of the methods people have posted functionally work to get me this string back *inside the function*.  But I still don't know how to assign it to a variable *outside of the function*.  I need `jsonString` to equal this text string, but I just don't know how to do that....

Comment: @JohnWu: It's no problem, but as I told you, you can't have it outside the function. Must be inside. Don't try to get around this. You need to learn to work with it. Any code that relies on the response must be in (or called from within) the callback function.

Comment: thank you, thank you, thank you for all your help!  Going through your code over and over made me FINALLY understand how to utilize the callback function.  Took me about 3 hours, but I finally got it :)

Comment: @JohnWu: You're welcome. Glad it helped. The async/callback style programming is really strange until it clicks. Good luck!

Answer (score 5):

Use JSON.stringify like so

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
```

Comment: @JohnWu: You shouldn't  `stringify` it. Just change the response headers so you're sending `text/plain`. Guessing right now you're sending `Content-Type: application/json`. This just doubles the work being done.

Comment: @JohnWu: Or if you can't change the headers, get the `.responseText` property from the XHR object. Should be available on the object passed as the 3rd parameter to the callback.

Comment: Lye - I updated my original question before I read your response... crazy.  How do I get `responseText` out of what `jQuery.get` returns?

Answer (score 1):

I think that you can use $.ajax as .get is using that under,, and define the dataType like this,, so no double parsings..

```
$.ajax({
  url: './polygons/1.json',
  method: "POST",
  dataType: "text"
});
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ says I should be able to use `dataType: "text"` but it's still coming back as the exact same parsed json....